# Extending a polynomial function on an interval to be infinitely differentiable on all of R

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $ f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial function, can it be extended to $ g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that g is infinitely many times differentiable and it is NOT the same polynomial?

What if we also assume that g has to be a polynomial, but not the same as f?

EDIT: I wasn't clear enough in the last question. Obviously g cannot be a different polynomial on all of the real line. But could it be f on (a,b) and then a different polynomial on the rest of $ \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: If $(a,b) \neq \mathbb{R}$, then yes. Multiply the polynomial with a cutoff function that is $\equiv 1$ on $(a,b)$. If $g$ has to be a polynomial, and $a < b$, then $g$ _must_ be the same polynomial by the identity theorem for (real-) analytic functions.

Comment: Look for *bump function* on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there are well-known $C^\infty$ functions with compact support.  That is, a function which is nonzero on a bounded interval, infinitely differentiable, but which are zero outside that interval.

So, to get a new $g$, just take the original polynomial $f$, then add a $C^\infty$ function to it whose "support" is outside $(a,b)$.

Note that $g$ cannot be made to be a polynomial, since then $f-g$ is a polynomial with infinitely many zeroes (namely, all of $(a,b)$) and is therefore the zero polynomial.